# Animate zoom in via center of an image in Android with xml

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I am trying to do some simple image zooming and panning with Android and I have two simple questions.

First, when I call the animation using `scale`, it zooms using the upper left-hand corner of the image as the origin but I would like it to zoom from the center of the image.
The second question is once the animation is done, it resets the image to the original state and I would like it to stay at the final state.

Here is the xml I have for the scale:

```
<scale android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:detachWallpaper="true"
    android:duration="3000"></scale>
```

and in my code:

```
a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.set);
a.reset();
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.clearAnimation();
iv.startAnimation(a);
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For scaling a image from center you have to set the pivotX and pivotY

try this code for scaling from center and retaining the state after scaling,

```
<scale  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXScale="1" 
  android:toXScale="5" 
  android:fromYScale="1" 
  android:toYScale="5" 
  android:pivotX="50%" 
  android:pivotY="50%" 
  android:duration="1000" 
  android:fillAfter="true">
</scale>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the zoom from the center!

Comment: I actually found out the fillAfter field does what I want.  It didn't work when I added it to the xml for some reason but when I did it manually in code it worked just fine.

Comment: @Mlove can you please post your code how to use fillafter manually hav been banging head for hours